# Open document from Sharepoint library not using "Name" field

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-designer

I have a requirement that is to open a document from a SharePoint library (a pdf in this case) using a field that I created. How can I replicate the behaviour of the "Name" field, in my field "Candidate Name"?

Property LinkToItem="true" allows me to open the library item itself and check all its fields, but that's not what I need.

I have also tried it through SPDesigner by encasing the 
 
in an  tag, but I can't seem to find the correct way to link to the file.

Answer (score 1):

For this, I will preface my advice with suggesting that you create a new view (so you don't wreck your default).

In SharePoint designer, edit the view and make sure you're in 'Split' mode in the bottom left 'Tag Properties' ribbon. Other options are Code and Design, just to further explain where it is.

Click on the column that you want to make a link, in your case Name, and by hovering over the element that is selected, a little arrow should appear on the right of the selected element. Click it, and select 'Show Link to Item'. Save and preview after hiding your Title column and place 'Name' as #1 and it will behave the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a multiline text field.  Just make it one line and do something like this inside of it.  Make sure it is a rich text field.

```
<a href="http://yoursite/Lists/My%20Custom%20List/Attachments/IDofListItem/Nameofthedoc.pdf">User Name</a>
```

It should come up as a link in the list